# What is the equivalent hook for both admin_head() and wp_head() combined, if any?

Tags: hooks

I know about `wp_head()` and `admin_head()` for hooking into their respective `<head>`s, but what is the hook for both of these combined, if any?

The purpose is to:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'custom_css');
add_action('admin_head', 'custom_css');
```

Just one `add_action()` instead of two would be cleaner.

**Edit**

Another question would be, *where can I find this information on my own?* I see an alphabetical list [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/), but I can't find any kind of firing order reference.

**Edit 2**

I don't think there is a hook for both. Correct me if I'm wrong. I'll delete this question if that's the case and the mods think it's a good idea.

Comment: I think this is a fair question, even if the answer is there isn't one. If I was looking myself I'd look for the code that triggers or handles wp_head and admin_head to see what else it calls nearby.

Comment: There isn’t one because there’s very very few circumstances where you would even want to do this. If you’re adding styles for editor content and front end content then `enqueue_block_assets` should be used to enqueue a stylesheet which will be used for the editor and the front end.

Comment: Someone post an answer or I can delete this question. I'd like to keep it up for my reference. e.g. *There is no global header hook*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no global head hook to target the front-end *and* back-end in WordPress.

My CSS needs to target the Admin Bar. Previewing a post/page while logged requires both `wp_head()` and `admin_head()`.